# Possible to ssh into a server without using -i flag for key?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, hadoop

I have 3 EC2 instances and they all use the same private key. I'm setting up a hadoop cluster between these nodes and they require passwordless entry for this to work.

How can I use this private key to easily ssh into the servers with keyless entry?

The only thing I have is a .pem file. I've scp'ed the file into the master server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a `~/.ssh/config` file with the necessary entries. The equivalent of the `-i` command line option is the `IdentityFile` command in the configuration file.

```
Host my.domain.com
  HostName other-name
  User me
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  Port 2222
  IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/other_keys/other_id_rsa
```

More info about the configuration file can be found in [man ssh_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** If you are to use many such keys, place them in a sub-directory otherwise you will get failures because ssh tries to login with all the keys found directly under `~/.ssh`. However, most servers will accept 3 to 5 attempts. More keys in the `.ssh` folder and it is likely to fail many login attempts unless you use the `-i` option or the configuration file.

Comment: @coderkid, if that's your solution then you may want to click on the big checkmark on the side of the answer to mark it as the one that made it work for you.